# Mongodb fluent aggregation and grouping in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregate, grouping, fluent

My .Net / C# application stores some information in Mongodb. The Mongodb documents have the following corresponding structure in C#:

```
public class GlobalInfo
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Population { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to extract from the Mongodb documents a `List<CountryInfo>` with all countries, or eventually as a `Dictionary<string, List<CityInfo>>` (the country name would be the dictionary key), based on the following classes:

```
public class CountryInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CityInfo> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class CityInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Population { get; set; }
}
```

I found some c# examples about similar functionality, realized with the help of the `Aggregate()`, `Match()`, `Group()` methods from the Mongodb C# driver. I am not sure how to use them for my example.

Basically I need to transform the flat list with Mongodb db documents into an hierarchical model, with nested lists or dictionary. Could somebody please help with some sample?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `group` keyword and group your entities by Country, then in the `select` you construct an object `CountryInfo` you can set the `Name` with the `Key` value from the group, the `Key` value is the Country name, then for the `Cities` you use the `Select` LinQ method that allows you to construct a list of another entity. You construct a `CityInfo` object with `Name = country.City` and `Population = country.Population` as shown below.

The `listGlobalInfo` is a list that contains all the documents from mongoDB and the type is `GlobalInfo`.

```
 var newList = from globalInfo in listGlobalInfo
                group globalInfo by globalInfo.Country into country
                    select new CountryInfo{ Name = country.Key, Cities = country.Select(city=> new CityInfo { Name = city.City, Population = city.Population}).ToList()};
```

If you want to see more example of `group` query you can go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results

Comment: Thank you for the sample. But actually I was looking for a solution using the fluent aggregation from the mongodb c# driver, something like this:  var results = myMongodbCollection.Aggregate().Group(
              x => x.Country,
              g => new {
                  CountryName = g.Key,
         ...

Comment: Oops my bad OP :) found this for some example https://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/mongodb-aggregation-framework-examples-in-c

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately not based on the newest mongodb c# driver, and no examples with the type safety when using lambda expressions.